# In Smallville, why does Kryptonite weaken people who got Superman's power but aren't Kryptonian?

Tags: dc, smallville, kryptonite

Kryptonite as seen in movies and comics only affects Kryptonian people at a biological level. However, in the TV series *Smallville*, people who stole the powers from him or got the powers from a different source still are weakened by Kryptonite even if they aren't Kryptonian. Why is it exactly that it weakens them when they have Superman's power?

It doesn't make sense that it affects humans with Superman's power, they aren't biologically Kryptonian so why would it affect them? Having the powers transfered makes the body just like a Kryptonian is my only guess.

Answer (score 1):

In *Smallville,* when exposed to green Kryptonite Clark's blood actually [boils](https://smallville.fandom.com/wiki/Clark_Kent%27s_blood). So it's likely that being infused with Clark's powers alters a person's body and/or blood at a biological level. (This is evident when Rudy returns Clark's powers to escape the pain of being exposed to Kryptonite.)

Comment: Basically if you have super-powers like a Kryptonian, kryptonite can harm you.